# Update arrays in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We have to update the bulk values in different arrays. 
Is there any way, we can update the values inside the different arrays at the same time ?

Currently, I have the path of the array, Old value and new values, I need to update lot of documents inside one collection - please do let me know if there is a way to do it in Mongodb 3.6 version.

For example:

**Path in the collection                  Old Value           New Value
orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productId      10001             10002
orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productName    Upto 2 Tst/1 Tst   Upto 33 Tst/22 Tst**

Comment: I would say it would be easy if you can give sample docs & required o/p..

Comment: Thanks for responding but the sample document is very big and I am trying to attach the tree structure for more understanding. Let me know if that helps you?

Comment: I cant attach here as I cant find any options.

Answer (score 0):

Please share your document structure so we can provide more specific direction. Assuming your document looks like:

```
{
  "orderDocument": {
    "customerOrderItems": {
      "customerOrderSubItems": [
        {
          "productId": 10004.0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reach the array through a path where value needs to be changed then use the '$' and name of the property to be updated:

```
db.getCollection('Event').updateMany(   
  {
    "orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productId": 10004
  },
  { 
    $set: {
      "orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.$.productId": 10005
    } 
  }
)
```

This gives the result.

Comment: In my case there are mulitple arrays within each key and to get to the desired value i tried these options:

Comment: Thanks for the output.In my case there are multiple arrays within each key and to get to the desired value i tried these options:  1st method of select option works only if i have 1 level of array for customerOrderSubItems and if i have muliple arrays for it the below query doesnt provide me the required productId: db.testcol.aggregate([{$unwind:"$orderDocument.customerOrderItems"},{$match:{"orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productId":"EP007"}},{$project:{"orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productId":1}}]).pretty()

Comment: this query for find works for me if i have multiple arrays for customerOrderSubItems: 
  
 db.customerOrder_noti.aggregate([{$unwind:"$orderDocument.customerOrderItems"},{$unwind:"$orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems"},{$match:{"orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productId":"EP0001"}},{$project:{"orderDocument.customerOrderItems.customerOrderSubItems.productId":1}}]).pretty()   == worked

Comment: so based on that for the second option --> how should i do update ?